# How to get all files PDF in device

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want get all files PDF in my phone. But When i use code new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).listFiles() return null. I am using targetSDK 31
My code

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
getfile(dir);
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if(listFile==null){
            Log.d("kdkkdd","day");
        }
       // Log.d("kkdkd",listFile.length+"");
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            Log.d("ssksks",listFile.length+"");
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    Log.d("kkdkkd",listFile[i].getName());
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {

                    boolean booleanpdf = false;
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                            if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                                booleanpdf = true;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        if (booleanpdf) {
                            booleanpdf = false;
                        } else {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("kdkdkkd",fileList.size()+"");
        return fileList;
    }
```

What solution fix ??? How to i can get all files PDF in my phone ???

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Specific storage permission? For targetSDK 31 you must have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to get PDF list.

> Permission required to fetch PDF

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> Then in your Manifest -> application tag to opt out scoped storage on Android 10 devices

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

> Take the storage permission at Run time from user. Then to fetch PDF

```
private void walkDir(File dir,String pattern) {
    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i=0;i<listFile.length;i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkDir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Simple call the method by

```
walkDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),".pdf")
```